# What is better way to name a package

Tags: java

What is the better way to name packages?

```
com.company.project.funtionality1.dao
com.company.project.funtionality1.vo
com.company.project.funtionality1.dto
com.company.project.funtionality1.controller
com.company.project.funtionality1.view

com.company.project.funtionality2.dao
com.company.project.funtionality2.vo
com.company.project.funtionality2.dto
com.company.project.funtionality2.controller
com.company.project.funtionality2.view
```

(or)

```
com.company.project.dao.functionality1
com.company.project.dao.functionality1

com.company.project.vo.funtionality1
com.company.project.vo.funtionality2

com.company.project.dto.funtionality1
com.company.project.dto.funtionality2

com.company.project.controller.funtionality1
com.company.project.controller.funtionality2

com.company.project.view.funtionality1
com.company.project.view.funtionality2
```

Comment: There is no "better" way - it depends on how _you and your team_ want to structure your code - although there are probably a lot of people that tend to put packages based on features/functionality first. However, as always there are other views and situations where using technical structures first might make more sense, e.g. if you split your application into api and implementation and don't do that on a project/artifact level.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is a good idea to follow the Common Reuse Principle:

*The classes in a package are reused together. If you reuse one of the classes in a package, you reuse them all.*

So, when you group packages by type (i.e. dao, service) that means to reuse one of the services, you need to grab all serives of your app. By grouping by functionality, when reusing a function you'll reuse all the necessary daos, services, controllers etc.